# Как работает выделение и освобождения памяти для процесса?

Tags: python, c++, linux, golang, ос

Если смотреть на определенном уровне абстракции то все понятно, мы запрашиваем у ОС память она нам выделяет страницы определенного размера и шлет их адреса.

Вопрос как это работает на более глубоком уровне.

1. Мы запустили новый процесс (прости бинарник скомпилированный), ему ОС уже выделила адреса, в какой момент она их выделила? можем ли мы получить все эти адреса? Для своего внутреннего использования.
2. После того как мы получили адреса, правильно ли я понимаю что нам больше нет необходимости обращаться к ОС и мы будем брать эти адреса из внутреннего стека уже внутри самой программы это контролировать?
3. Если в какой то момент мы запускаем сборщик мусора python\golang освобождает ли он память обратно для ОС или он освобождает только внутри приложения для повторного использования? Т.е. фактически он просто возвращает адреса страниц памяти в внутренний стек процесса в котором хранятся адреса куда можно что-то записать?

Comment: Эти механизмы очень сложны, их реализация в python и c++ вообще разная.

Comment: а глобально для ОС, в какой момент она выделяет первые страницы и как их получить, процесс сам это может сделать после запуска?

Comment: Это вам нужно какие-то специализированные тексты по конкретным языкам читать. Везде реализация мемори менеджмента довольно своеобразная, в каждом конкретном языке.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну вопрос 1,2 не к конкретным языкам как раз. А к ОС.

Comment: @ПавелКозлов Но ведь бинарник на чём-то да написан. Если он написан на ассемблере, то вы напрямую будете обращаться к API ОС и говорить "хочу блок памяти такого-то размера". И освобождать память тоже будете сами, если захотите. А если бинарник на высокоуровневом ЯП написан, то надо смотреть как конкретный ЯП менеджит память.

Comment: @CrazyElf не совсем. Вроде как под процесс изначально выделяется определенный объем при старте. Про это как раз вопрос 1,2. Ну и какая разница на чем написал бинарник если мы будем в любом случае общаться с ОС через системные вызовы.

Comment: @ПавелКозлов Какая-то часть выделяется сразу, какая-то в процессе работы уже. Если программа на языке высокого уровня, то с ОС будет общаться ядро этого языка по мере надобности, ваша программа с ОС напрямую общаться не будет. Чем более высокоуровневый язык, тем меньше программа напрямую общается с ОС и железом.

Comment: @CrazyElf выделяется сразу куда, и как с ней работать? Как из программы понять что именно мне выделено уже поумолчанию?

Comment: разберитесь для начала со стеком и кучей

Comment: @ПавелКозлов И снова это зависит от конкретного языка программирования. И ещё от формата бинарного файла, почитайте описание конкретного формата, в котором получается ваша программа.

Comment: @CrazyElf т.е. грубо говоря бинарник может сказать ОС сколько ему нужно выделить и положить ему в стек адреса этих первых N страниц? И соответственно процесс знает что у него по смещению 0x0001-0x00FF лежат адреса страниц выделенных ему? Ну опять же понятно что это все разное, я хочу понятно общий принцип примерные.

Comment: Да нету общего принципа, нету, насколько я понимаю. Надо читать спецификации на всё - на форматы файлов, на конкретные языки, на конкретную ОС.

Comment: @CrazyElf я все равно не особо понимаю. Можете привести пример на каком то конкретном языке тогда. Но я не понимаю причем тут язык, выделяет память же ОС процессу. Конкретно ОС вобще не важно на каком языке написан бинарник.

Comment: @eri т.е. ОС выделяем при запуске память только под стек причем фиксированный, а под кучу память выделяется во время работы программы и хранятся адреса как раз в стеке ?

Comment: да. или по пунктам: 1) ос выделяет весь стек полностью сразу, кучу выделяет когда программа попросит (`malloc`-`free`) 2) стек фиксированный и где какая переменная лежит определяет компилятор, а с кучей можно играться как хотите в пределах того что разрешает ОС или будет segfault. 3) python освобождает, а вот Java забирает память у ОС большими кусками(страницами) и внутри процесса перераспределяет её - назад не отдает сразу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я занимался этими вопросами много много лет назад, поэтому возможно сейячас появилось и что-то более новое, но тем не менее.

Если вы действительно хотите понять принципы, то начинать надо не с вопросов на форуме, а с чтения основополагающих книг. Ну например, уже много поколений программистов учатся по книге

```
Таненбаум Э., Бос Х. Современные операционные системы
```

И хоть книга не новая, но принципы они на то и принципы, что не меняются десятилетиями. В общем - ОЧЕНЬ рекомендую.

Далее, когда разберетесь с фундаментаом, нужно смотреть уже как "оно" работает в конкретной ОС. Так, для систем семейства  Windows найти можно по ключевому слову WinAPI. Есть описания работы по выделению памяти в Windows системах у разных авторов. Ну например:

```
Побегайло А.П. Системное программирование в Windows. 
Щупак Ю. А.  Win32 API. Эффективная разработка приложений.
Безруков В.А. Win32 API. Программирование/учебное пособие
Литвиненко Н. А. Технология программирования на С++. Win32 API-приложения. 
Рихтер Дж., Назарр К. Windows via C/C++. Программирование на языке Visual C++
Харт Д.  Системное программирование в среде Windows.
```

Много чего можно найти на сайте Microsoft. Но в любом случае подчеркну, ни один из приведенных источников вы не поймете, если предварительно не освоите "фундамент". Это я не занудствую, это просто многолетний опыт, как практической работы системного программирования так и преподавания, в том числе и рассматриваемых  вопросов.

Поскольку управление памяти - это один из самых внутренних слоев любой ОС, то во первых, что-бы непосредственно посмотреть "что там и как" придется предварительно освоить хакинг. Начиная, с того, как что-то запускать в режиме "ядра". И приципов работы на уровне системных вызовов.  Но по крайней мере, в книгах, приведенных выше вы можете (если сумеете) использовать С++. (Потому как изначально доступ был только на уровне ассемблера, потом API немного "подняли"). В общем смотрите источники, а далее - углубляйтесь по мере наличия (или пропажи) интереса.

Что касается Linux/Android и пр. то также попадались аналогичные источники, только попадались они мне уже тогда, когда для меня вопрос утратил актуальность. Но если надо искать - ключевые слова "системный вызов", "(низкоуровневое) управление памятью", "виртуализация памяти" и т.д.

Удачи.

Comment: Спасибо, Таненбаум уже начал читать! Вопрос немного попроще на самом деле. Т.е. правильно ли я понимаю что у меня запустилось приложение и ОС выделила под него 4мб, они все в данный момент выделены под стек. Далее когда приложение запросило выделение данные в куче ОС выделила страницу и отдала приложению адрес, причем в приложении мы как бы записали в свой стек адрес этой страницы и уже работает внутри с ним пока страница не закончится и тогда запросим новую. Ну то есть я не про конкретную реализацию, а про принцип, он может быть примерно такой?

Comment: Смотря кто "мы". Ваша программа ничего этого не делает. Предположим, речь идет о компилируемом языке, вы создали exe-модуль или что-то ему подобное в других систем. После компиляции становиться известно, сколько памяти надо, что-бы процесс начал работу. Когда ОС запускает процесс (обратите внимание, не "вы" написав название в командной строке, а именно ОС, которая прочла эту строку, поискала и нашла нужный файл, вытянула из него нужную информацию, ЗАПРОСИЛА сама себя (именно так, просто обратившись к другим функциям-системным вызовам)  нужный объем ОП, получила ее, загрузила туда файл

Comment: После этого управление передается этому файлу и начинает работать его процесс. В ходе его работы о может в случае необходимости "дозаказать" у ОС еще памяти, может часть освободить. Соответствующие команды встроены в ваш eхе файл на этапе компилятора самим компилятором.  Естественно -  с соответствующей логикой, когда эти действия выполнять.  А вот с выделеной памятью вы вольны работать как хотите, например, генерировать в них объекты или удалять в них (помните, в С++ операторы new и delete). Но эта работа идет внутри выделенной памяти. А вот "подкачка" нужных страниц -

Comment: т.е. выгрузка части пространства памяти во временный файл или обратная подкачка) - это уже преоргатива самой ОС. Вы (т.е. ваш процесс) об этом никогда и не узнает. Т.е. они будут выполняться,  но на выполнении процесса это никак не повлияет (ну, не считая некоторого его замедления).

Comment: да. но моя программа же эти адреса выделенные куда то сохраняет и как то с ними работают, соответственно они лежат на стеке, который выделен заранее при запуске ОС. И у меня прям в бинарнике грубо говоря написано "запроси у ОС 64байта памяти и положи адрес на них в стек", дальше в бинарнике когда нужно моя же программа знает что в стеке лежит адрес по которому расположены нужные мне 64байта, а уж куда ОС реально это положила и какой там реально адрес будет лежать решает только ОС - это понятно.

Comment: Вы немного путаете.  Управление ОП -  это не однослойный процесс "моя программа запрашивает память, ОС выделяет, моя программа работает". Там много слоев взаимных вызовов системных API.  О большинстве из которых ваша программа и не подозревает.  Причем опять спрошу, что такое "ваша программа"? Написанный вами код, при превращении в еxе модуль оборачивается таким объемом всяких системных вызовов, что сам ваш код там и не разглядеть. И еще один "слой ОС" выбеляет память, другой слой системных вызовов позволяет вашему модулю работать с какой-то частью этой памяти как со стеком.

Comment: В бинарнике действительно есть обращение к стеку. Но это никак не связано с выделением памяти. А преобразование логических адресов, которые присутствуют в вашей программе в физические адреса -  это вообще отдельная тема. Учитывая, что страницы памяти могут выгружаться подгружаться, то в разные моменты времени одна и та же "переменная"  может лежать в совершенно  различных физических ячейках физической памяти, хотя никаких операций по ее перемещению ни программист, ни даже "ваш бинарник" не предусматривал.

Comment: Я понимаю о чем вы пишете. Я почитал и про динамическое выделение памяти и про страничную организацию памяти. Но немогу увязать их вместе как они работают. Когда я запрашиваю у ОС 8байт и памяти свободной нет ОС вылепляет мне эту память но выделяет она страницу сразу. Если я потом запрашиваю еще 8байт это опять будет запрос через ОС или Язык/компилятор как то это сам запоминает что есть страница выделенная ? И тоже самое с освобождение мы просто освобождаем байты и ОС сама понимает когда мы освободили всю страницу чтобы могла выдать ее кому то другому ?

Comment: 1. Да, в случае необходимости(!!!) на уровне ОС память выделяется не побайтно, а страницами. 2. Нет никаких "сначала" и "потом". На уровне процесса -  выполняется обращение к памяти (Ну например new).  Если ОС обнаруживает,  что памяти хватает из ранее выделенной -  то все ОК. Если нет - и если ОС (!!)  обнаруживает, что вы имеете право на расширение своего виртуального пространства памяти -  то она это сделает. Если нет -  произойдет исключение - "переполнение адресного пространства".  То-же самое при освобождении.  Повторяю, управление памяти - это очень (!) многослойный пирог.

Comment: 2. Под «потом» я имел ввиду условно две разных строчки кода которые запрашивают *int8 в разных местах. Допустим первая вернула адрес 0004 Если как вы говорите ОС выделяет не сразу страницу, то как она поймёт при втором вызове что нужно выделить адрес сразу после первой переменной 0012, и что условно какой то другой процесс не записал туда свои данные? ОС же точно не хранит все адреса ранее выданные по 8байт

Comment: Мне тут уже прислали предупреждение, что форум -  не место для таких развернутых объяснений. Да и объяснил я уже вроде все. По третьему разу как-то даже не знаю, как объяснять. Вы все таки посмотрите книжечки, которые я привел выше. Там есть ответы на ваши вопросы. А вот если что-то в них останется конкретно непонятное -  ну давайте тогда и вернемся к продолжению обсуждения. Удачи.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в ответе нет собственно ответа на вопрос. Рекомендации книжек это хорошо, но нужен ответ. Вопросы в комментариях потому и возникли, потому что ответа нет. Вместо того, чтоб в комментариях пробовать отвечать, лучше отредактируйте ответ и добавьте в него то, что пробуете в комментариях писать.